# How to encode EOL-CR/LF in Delphi XE on Win 7 64 for MS NotePad?

Tags: character-encoding, newline, delphi-xe, email-attachments, notepad

I am using Delphi XE with Indy 10 SMTP client (`TIdSMTP`) - on a Win 7 64 machine. I'm generating a simple text file report that is sent as an email attachment with the `*.txt` extension. Users will normally be viewing the report attachment with MS Win Notepad.exe, the default Win 7 text editor ***(That cannot/will not change).***

As always, I used `#13+#10` in this project to represent `CR/LF` in Delphi strings. Never had  a problem with it (although I never had to use it in Notepad AFAIK.)

But I found that the `#13+#10 - CR/LF` is **ignored** in Notepad.exe - as if it's not there, although the EOL in the attachment is recognized and rendered properly in every other editor I have around, Including NotePad++, MS Write, MS Word, Delphi, EditPad, etc. etc... I know there are problems with Notepad.exe dealing with `CR` alone or `LF` alone but I thought `CR/LF` always worked - but it isn't working here.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a unicode or 64 bit issue? How/what do I have to embed in my string in Delphi XE on Win7 64 platform, so that Notepad.exe will recognize and render properly `EOL - CR/LF.`

***Relevant code as per Remy's comment:***

```
const
  EOL = #13+#10;
  EMAIL_TITLE2 = 'Value expressed in $ 000''s' + EOL;
  REPORT_NAME='Report';

var
  list: TStringList;
  s: string;
  ...
begin    
  ...
  list.Add (EMAIL_TITLE2)
  ... add more text lines + EOL;

  s := list.Text;

  Attachment := TIdAttachmentMemory.Create(msg.MessageParts, s);
  Attachment.FileName := REPORT_NAME + '.txt';
  smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

Comment: I can assure you that Notepad DOES NOT ignore `CRLF` line breaks.  So your attachment is likely not actually using `CRLF` correctly. Please show your actual code. How exactly are you generating the text file? Are you sending the text file using `TIdText` or `TIdAttachment` in Indy?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - is it possible that using TStringList.text is corrupting the CR/LF and only the CR or only the LF is going out? I know in the past I have run into some funky behavior with TStringList.text. Will have to examine the output carefully...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indy has its own `EOL` constant for `#13#10`, so you do not need to declare your own constant.

Do not include line breaks when adding a `string` to the `TStringList`.  Let `Add()` handle the line break for you.  If you need to `Add()` a string with line breaks in it, split the string first and `Add()` the pieces.  And if your code is running on a non-Windows system, use the `TStringList.LineBreak` property to specify `#13#10` as the line break used when outputting text, otherwise a platform-specific default is used instead.

Something else to watch out for is that `TIdAttachmentMemory` will encode a `string` using Indy's default charset, which is set to ASCII by default.  So if you are sending text with non-ASCII characters in it, use `TStringList.SaveToStream()` so you can specify whatever encoding you want, such as UTF-8, and then have `TIdAttachmentMemory` send that `TStream` data instead of the original `string`.  You can either save the `TStringList` to your own `TStream`, such as a `TMemoryStream` or `TStringStream`, and pass that to the `TIdAttachmentMemory` constructor, or you can use the `TIdAttachmentMemory.PrepareTempStream()` method to get a `TStream` owned by `TIdAttachmentMemory` that you can write data to.

Try this:

```pascal
const
  EMAIL_TITLE2 = 'Value expressed in $ 000''s';

var
  list: TStringList;
  strm: TStream;
  ...
begin    
  ...
  list.LineBreak := #13#10;
  ...
  list.Add (EMAIL_TITLE2);
  ... add more text lines

  Attachment := TIdAttachmentMemory.Create(msg.MessageParts);
  Attachment.ContentType := 'text/plain';
  Attachment.CharSet := 'utf-8';
  Attachment.FileName := ReportName + '.txt';
  strm := Attachment.PrepareTempStream;
  try
    list.SaveToStream(strm, TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    Attachment.FinishTempStream;
  end; 

  smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

Comment: OK- will go over it Monday. I am adding another `EOL` besides what `TStringList.add` provides because I need an extra space between lines - "double spaced". I was thinking that with unicode strings, appending raw ASCII chars in the string won't work right because they're only one byte each, so the unicode 2 byte structure would be corrupted. The reason it works in other editors is because the `#13` is enough for the EOL - just notepad needs also the `#10` which is getting trashed in unicode.

Comment: To add an extra line break between two strings, simply `Add()` a blank string. You are misunderstanding how ASCII and Unicode strings actually work.

Comment: _You are misunderstanding how ASCII and Unicode strings actually work_ - could be. I suppose that the string is allocated as unicode and properly aligned. I will try it without using any EOL characters at all.

Comment: I used the stream and set the encoding - that did it.